# JSONSchema Resource that hints at its schema

Tags: python, jsonschema

I'm trying to discover the best way to get a resource to somehow indicate the schema that should be used to validate it.

I need this because there may come a time where I need to return an array full of different resources. In this case I'd need each resource in the array to tell me what schema it is supposed to be validated with.

What is the best way to do this?

My idea is to use a nested JSONSchema whereby the outer object has the name of the resource (eg. car):

```
{
  'type': 'object',
  'properties': {
    'car': {
        {
          'type': 'object',
          'title': 'car',
          'properties': OrderedDict([('id', {
              'type': 'integer'
          })]),
          'required': ['id']
    }
  },
  'required': [
    'car'
  ]
}
```

I can then clearly see in the resource which schema it's supposed to be validated with:

```
{
    'car': {
        'id': 1,
    }
}
```

Then in the situation where I need to return an array of different resources, each resource can be easily identified and validated correctly:

```
{
    'items': [
        {
            'car': {
                'id': 1,
            }
        },
        {
            'helicopter': {
                'id': 1,
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do they need to be validated by the client? Validate them server side and if you can't send valid objects reply with an error.

Comment: Trouble is, if the server receives an array of objects from a client, how can it know which schemas to use to validate each resource in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to handle something like this in JSON Schema is to use the `anyOf` constraint.

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "anyOf": [
      { "$ref": "car.json" },
      { "$ref": "helicopter.json" }
    ]
  }
}
```

This way the client doesn't need to tell you what schema to use, you tell the client which schemas are allowed.  Validation succeeds as long every item in the array matches one of the possible options.

If you need to be more specific about the items in the array, you can restructure the schema to isolate the types.

Comment: Seems like a nice solution, thanks Jason. I'll just wait a while before marking this as my answer in case another answer comes.